# why node express sees django's boolean as string?

Tags: python, node.js, django, express, types

Due to some reasons, I have a `django` backend that needs to make another request to a `express nodejs`'s api call but somehow the `express` is seeing `boolean` field `django` passed as `string`
how can I fix this issue?

example of django part

```
    payload = {
        "verified": True
    }
    e = requests.post('http://api', payload).json()
```

as for `express` part, I just used `console.log(res.body)` and also checked the `typeof` for example

```
console.log(req.body);  // {verified: 'True'}
console.log(typeof(req.body.verified));  // string
```

This is causing `mongoose` not able to query the boolean field wanted

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> e = requests.post('http://api', payload).json()

`.json()` function is used for response.

In order to post `JSON` use `json` keyword argument.

See example below.

```
payload = {
    "verified": True
}
e = requests.post('http://api', json=payload)
```

Now everything should be OK with types in express.